# PHP exec is not calling the function or gives deadlock

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a js script that i want to call with "node" from php. This script is exporting a php file. My code looks like this:

```
$commandString = 'node ' . $nodejsPath . ' ' . $pdfDirectory . ' ' . $url . ' ' . $pdfFileName;
exec($commandString);
return Redirect::back();
```

Problem is that this code is working from cmd, but not from my website. If i push the button that triggers this command, i get the loading page for unlimited time.

I'm using puppeteer. I tried ending the command with 2>&1 but this still didn't work. The url is good, pdfFileName is generated correctly, the $nodejsPath is good. I went into the controller file and ran the exact command from above and it worked.

Expected results: call the controller function(exportPDF) which will export a pdf file for me.
Actual result: deadlock (i think)

Comment: use the second parameter of exec to see if there is any output (if it does finish)

Comment: It could be that `exec` is blocked by your hoster because of security concerns.

Comment: Please ensure you use `escapeshellarg` to prevent `exec` from being abused.

Comment: @blues the process does not finish

Comment: @Geoffrey now it does end, but the script is not called. escapeshellarg puts another pare of "" on my string

Comment: @CodeSpirit exec is not blocked by my hoster. I went in php.ini and it is not in disable_functions

Comment: @Sami, I did not suggest to use `escapeshellarg` to fix your script, but to prevent it from being abused to attack your website.